# Specify the connection_factory to SQLAlchemy's create_engine()

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have a custom connection factory class (which inherits from `psycopg2.extensions.connection`) that I would like SQLAlchemy to use. From the `create_engine()` documentation,

> **kwargs takes a wide variety of options which are routed towards their appropriate components. Arguments may be specific to the Engine,
>   the underlying Dialect, as well as the Pool. Specific dialects also
>   accept keyword arguments that are unique to that dialect.

When I try to specify a connection_factory parameter, like this:

`engine = create_engine(dsn.engine_info(), connection_factory=ConnectionEx)`

I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "foo.py", line 8, in <module>
    from user import test_user   File "/vagrant/workspace/panel/panel/user.py", line 18, in <module>
    from panel.helpers import intval   File "/vagrant/workspace/panel/panel/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    import panel.views   File "/vagrant/workspace/panel/panel/views.py", line 13, in <module>
    from panel.api import api_functions   File "/vagrant/workspace/panel/panel/api/api_functions.py", line 27, in <module>
    from panel.targeting import SavedTargetSet   File "/vagrant/workspace/panel/panel/targeting.py", line 19, in <module>
    from panel.database import panelists_tbl, us_cities_tbl, income_buckets_tbl   File "/vagrant/workspace/panel/panel/database.py", line 39, in <module>
    engine = create_engine(dsn.engine_info(), connection_factory=ConnectionEx)   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 331, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 141, in create
    engineclass.__name__)) TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'connection_factory' sent to create_engine(), using configuration PGDialect_psycopg2/QueuePool/Engine.  Please check that the keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the documentation is talking about "appropriate components," its referring to the components of the SQLAlchemy API, rather than the various drivers. Since `connection_factory` is a parameter that needs to be sent to `connect()`, you should use the keyword `connect_args` in your call to `create_engine` ([documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine) also mentioned [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#custom-dbapi-connect-arguments)). Thus:

```
engine = create_engine(
    dsn.engine_info(), connect_args={'connection_factory': ConnectionEx})
```